# cambio de año en fecha

Tags: vba

hola estoy en un programa que funcionaba excelente hasta el año pasado, hacia consultas de fechas en una base de datos de access, pero solo consulta las fechas hasta diciembre, desde enero todas las que son del año 2021 no las consigue, este es el codigo, vba excel, el detalle estan en el evento de cambio de fecha del datepicker, al hacer la consulta el recordset queda vacio porque no consigue la fecha, pero solo para el año 2021 las del 2020 las consulta sin problemas, si hago la consulta sin convertir la variable en string me da error de no coinciden los tipos

```
Sub buscot()
'verificar que haya un apartamento
If ComboBox1.Text = "Seleccione" Then
Exit Sub
End If
'buscar lacotizacion del dia
If DTPicker1.Value = "" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
Dim fic As Date
    Dim fec, cot As String
    fic = DTPicker1.Value
    'SELECT cotizaciones.cotizacion FROM Cotizaciones WHERE (((Cotizaciones.[fecha]) = #11/30/2020#))
    Dim lis As String
    fec = CStr(fic)
    lis = "select cotizacion from cotizaciones where fecha = #" & Format(fec, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "#" ' #" + fic + "#"
    '" + limpio + "'
    rs.Open lis, miconexion, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    cot = CStr(rs.Fields(0).Value)
        If cot = "" Then
            MsgBox "No hay cotizacion para fecha seleccionada...", vbOKOnly, "Error de Datos"
            CommandButton1.Enabled = False
            TextBox9.Text = ""
            Else
            TextBox9.Text = FormatNumber(cot, 2)
            CommandButton1.Enabled = True
            'si consigue la cotizacion hacer el calculo
            Call HaceCalc
        End If
End If
rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Por favor, simplifica el código. Has puesto demasiado, pon solo el procedimiento que te da error. Si facilitas la lectura de tu pregunta, es más factible que alguien ayude. Si complicas la lectura, más difícil. De todas formas, si los de 2020 los lee sin problemas peor los de 2021 no, tiene pinta de ser un problema en los valores, no en el código

Comment: editada,muchas gracias, la cosa es que con las todos los datos provienen de la misma fuente, es la misma base de datos

Comment: y en la db hay datos del 2021? el codigo esta bien sin importar la fecha...

Comment: `fic = DTPicker1.Value` esto es lo que debes mirar, el `DTPicker1.Value` es el que contiene la fecha, no aparece en el código así que no sé a qué se refiere. Entiendo que será un combobox, debéis rellenar ese combobox con fechas del 2021